# generation of word from Latex

Tags: latex-to-word

My question: is there any way that wa can generate a word output file from latex ?

Input : latex file
output: word file instead of pdf

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can also check pandoc for a CLI tool. It works ok for documents (even with figures and equations), except for tables. It's better to defineyour own MSWord template in beforehand. Generates a List of References, but not automated. Cross-refs are also a bit buggy (notably if you use `cleveref`and/or `varioref`).

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools are available, Chikri, GrindEq are some of the commercial converters, and L2R, TeX4ht are some of the free converters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I have already tried L2R for example, it is very complicated and I didn't see how it works; that needs the preparation of a complex environment. I don't find a simple way to convert latex to word

Comment: No converter produces exact conversion from TeX to Word, all the converter produces 50-60% quality and we need to take care some parts manually, e.g., Reference styles, cross links, complex equations, etc...